# How to Get element Position - Imacros

Tags: javascript, html, imacros

I have 3 different types of HTML Elements (repeated , dynamic values, i can't count the numbers) first type elements have same attribute (class) , but different in text (i can get the element across the text) , the other 2 have same attributes (i can get this element across the Position) , so i want to click on the other 2 types across  the Position of first type of elements , for this i want to know first type element Position (what i found across the text) according first type elements Positions (as all) , what i have to do to get the Position of repeated element i have found ?!

**EDIT:**

Example:

```
<div class="class1">Text1</div> //i want it (the pos here is 1 , for both all elements and imacros)
<div class="class2"></div> //i want to click on it
<div class="class1">Text2</div>
<div class="class1">Text1</div> //And it (the pos here is 3 to all elements , but 2 in imacros)
<div class="class2"></div> //i want to click on it too
<div class="class1">Text3</div>
<div class="class1">Text4</div>
```

Comment: @Tienkamp thanks for your help , i resolved it and i put the answer , [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42877577/7716032) , thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Example2:

```
<div class="class1">Text1</div>
<div class="class1">Text2</div>
<div class="class1">Text3</div>
<div class="class1">Text4</div>
<div class="class1">Text5</div> //i found this element by text , i want to know (Programmatically with imacros) the POSITION of this element (according to same elements (Similar in some attributes (like class in this case)))
<div class="class1">Text6</div>
<div class="class1">Text7</div>
<div class="class1">Text8</div>
<div class="class1">Text9</div>
<div class="class1">Text10</div>
```

i resolved it by "for function" , but with javascript language help ..

my code: in (.js) file ..

```
for (var i=1;i<10;i++)
{
var macro = "CODE: ";
macro += "SET !ERRORIGNORE YES\n";
macro += "SET !EXTRACT NULL\n";
macro += "TAG POS={{i}} TYPE=DIV ATTR=class:class1 EXTRACT=TXT\n";
iimPlay(macro);
if(iimGetLastExtract().search("TEXT5")!=-1)
{
alert("element pos is: " + i)
}
}
```